# How to Pull request certain files?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, pull-request

I have to Pull request certain files from my repository to the original repository.I have already forked a repository. I pushed my changes to the forked repository. But when i pull request it shows all the files which are Modified during the last Commit.

I need to give Pull request only for the Files in this folder app/src/*.

How can i Pull request for Certain Files ???

Answer (score 0):

You could crate a branch, pull all files, and copy the files you need manually to your other branch:

```
git checkout -b BRANCH_NAME
```

copy those files

```
git checkout PREVIOUS_BRANCH_NAME
```